# Why celery beat doesn't schedule periodic tasks?

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I've followed the celery doc https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html to create an app and periodic tasks as below:

```
$ tree demo/
demo/
├── config.py
├── __init__.py
└── tasks.py

$ cat demo/__init__.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('demo')
app.config_from_object('demo.config')

$ cat demo/config.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
CELERY_TIMEZONE='UTC'
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    "demo.tasks",
]

$ cat demo/tasks.py 
from demo import app
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(3.0, say.s(), name='say hello every 3s')

@app.task
def say():
    print("Hello!")
```

And then run celery beat as below:

```
$ celery beat -A demo -l info --max-interval 10
celery beat v4.3.0 (rhubarb) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2019-12-12 16:26:41
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 10.00 seconds (10.0s)
[2019-12-12 16:26:41,234: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

Wait for a while, there isn't any task scheduled.

However if I change to set `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` in config, it can work well. I do that by changing `demo/config.py` and `demo/tasks.py` as below:

```
$ cat demo/config.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import timedelta

BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"

CELERY_TIMEZONE='UTC'
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    "demo.tasks",
]

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'say hello every 10 seconds': {
         'task': 'demo.tasks.say',
         'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3),
    },
}
$ cat demo/tasks.py 
from demo import app

@app.task
def say():
    print("Hello!")
```

Then run celery beat with the same command as before, the periodic tasks can be scheduled every 3 seconds as expected.

What's wrong with my previous setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, I figured out another solution, changing the decorator `@app.on_after_configure.connect` to `@app.on_after_finalize.connect` can make it work. Though I don't know the exact reason at this moment.

Comment: I ran into this myself.  It's because `on_after_configure` is sent at the end of `celery.py`, but the `tasks.py` module isn't loaded until much later (`autodiscover_tasks()` doesn't execute immediately because Django has to finish setting up apps.)  So any periodic task decorated with `on_after_configure` isn't imported until long after `on_after_configure` is sent.  PR explaining the issue here: https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/6031

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the scheduler by `--scheduler` key according [this userguide](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). For example you could try something like this code below:

```
celery beat -A demo -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

P.S. I don't sure that `--max-interval` not interfere with your schedule period. Think is better to remove this option. IMHO.

Comment: The default scheduler is "celery.beat.PersistentScheduler" as you can see in the output of celery beat command.

Answer (score 0):

Celery 4.x does not use the upper-case config variables - see the [New lowercase settings](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings) section of the Celery documentation. Scheduler-specific configuration arguments are listed [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#beat-settings-celery-beat). So, try to modify your code to have `beat_schedule = {` instead of `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {`. The link you say you followed also uses lower-case names...

Comment: upper-case config variables also works because Celery 4.x also support old format config, and in my example, "CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE" works well. What doesn't work is the original version of code which uses "@app.on_after_configure.connect" + "setup_periodic_tasks".